# ¿Cómo validar una cantidad exacta de caracteres de un string?

Tags: c#

En este caso mi código deja introducir hasta 8 caracteres, pero a su vez deja introducir 7,6,5, etc... se puede controlar en ese mismo código que sean 8 obligatoria mente y no menos.

```
cedula = Console.ReadLine();
if (cedula == "")
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    mensaje = "\n" + "La cedula es obligatoria";
}
else if (cedula.Length > 8)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    mensaje = mensaje + "\n" + "La cedula debe tener 8 numeros obligatoriamente\n";
}
```

Comment: Por cierto son varias preguntas que escribes que comienzan con "Duda sobre xxx", creo que puedes mejorar un poco en la redacción de los títulos para que refleje exactamente el problema

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplemente compáralo con el operador `!=`

```
else if (cedula.Length != 8)
```

Así entrará en la condición sino son exactamente 8 caracteres

Comment: Creo que el problema va mas alla.. todo esto deberia estar envuelto en un while que no esta mostrando...

Comment: @gbianchi bueno ese es otro tema

Comment: te puedo asegurar que a franco le falta eso (como si ya lo hubiera corregido varias veces ;) )

Comment: Solucionado,gracias!